# How does "gsub" handle spaces?

Tags: regex, r

I have a character string `"ab b cde"`, i.e. `"ab[space]b[space]cde"`. I want to replace "space-b" and "space-c" with blank spaces, so that the output string is `"ab[space][space][space][space]de"`. I can't figure out how to get rid of the second "b" without deleting the first one. I have tried:

```
gsub("[\\sb,\\sc]", " ", "ab b cde", perl=T)
```

but this is giving me `"a[spaces]de"`. Any pointers?  Thanks.

Edit: Consider a more complicated problem: I want to convert the string `"akui i ii"` i.e. `"akui[space]i[space]ii"` to `"akui[spaces|"` by removing the `"space-i"` and `"space-ii"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [lookbehind matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this:

```
gsub("(?<=\\s)i+", " ", "akui i ii", perl=T)
```

*Edit:
lookbehind is still the way to go, demonstrated with an other example from your original post. Hope this helps.*

Comment: jupp0r... The code doesn't seem to work for "akui i ii" which I included into the original posting. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`[\sb,\sc]` means "one character among space, `b`, `,`, space, `c`".
You probably want something like `(\sb|\sc)`, which means "space followed by `b`, or space followed by `c`"
or `\s[bc]` which means "space followed by `b` or `c`".

```
s <- "ab b cde"
gsub( "(\\sb|\\sc)",     "  ", s, perl=TRUE )
gsub( "\\s[bc]",         "  ", s, perl=TRUE )
gsub( "[[:space:]][bc]", "  ", s, perl=TRUE )  # No backslashes
```

To remove multiple instances of a letter (as in the second example) include a `+` after the letter to be removed.

```
s2 <- "akui i ii"
gsub("\\si+", " ", s2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Vincent. But it doesn't work for "akui i ii" (Please see my edit to the original post).

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple solution to this.

```
    gsub("\\s[bc]", " ", "ab b cde", perl=T)
```

This will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
x<-"ab b cde"
gsub(" b| c", "  ",x)
```

Note the **double** spaces in the 2nd argument.